# React Native vector icons: why is `back_arrow` failing to render?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons, vector-icons

I'm using `react-native-vector-icons` in my React Native app, and have the following component:

```
<Icon
  name='rowing'
/>
```

I used the `rowing` icon because that was the first example in [the documentation here](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.html). When you don't supply a value for `type`, it defaults to `material`, so I figured I could replace `rowing` with any of the `material` icons from [this list](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=arrow_back_ios&style=baseline). When I replaced it with `back_arrow`, it renders as a question mark. Does anyone know how I can approach debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ejected project make sure that you bundle the library correctly in the android studio [here are the full instructions](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/README.md)

Otherwise, if you are using expo make sure to use the correct library:
[Expo lib](https://github.com/expo/vector-icons)

Answer (score 0):

Checklist

1. Have you done, npm install react-native-elements

As mentioned here, https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html

2. Please cross check in package.json file do u have dependency of "react-native-elements"